# Using Distinct returns duplicate values.How to avoid this?

Tags: mysql, sql

Query:

```
  select distinct (Customer) ,CustomerID from history where Customer != '' and        Customer LIKE 'Ram%';
```

Results:

```
      Ramer ram100
      Raman ra45
      Raman ra45
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using `MAX` and `group by`.

```
 select Customer, MAX(CustomerID) CustomerID
 from   history
 where  Customer != '' AND Customer LIKE 'Ram%'
 GROUP BY Customer
```

Comment: @kurya: customerID is also string datatype.

Comment: it doesn't matter. by the way, just to more clear, can you add sample recordfs with desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see all customer ids as well, use [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
select customer, group_concat(distinct customerid)
from history
where Customer != '' and Customer like 'Ram%'
group by customer
```